# Problems multithreading with cluster on Node.JS(Express + socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

Here is the guide I'm basing my code off of: https://github.com/elad/node-cluster-socket.io

Although 9 threads are started, only one is in use at a time, and it's always the same thread that gets used. Their code works fine, but I've modified it to work with my program, and that's where I'm having issues.

manager.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
cluster = require('cluster'),
net = require('net'),
sio = require('socket.io'),
sio_redis = require('socket.io-redis');

var port = 3000,
    num_processes = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // This stores our workers. We need to keep them to be able to reference
    // them based on source IP address. It's also useful for auto-restart,
    // for example.
    var workers = [];

    // Helper function for spawning worker at index 'i'.
    var spawn = function(i) {
        workers[i] = cluster.fork();

        // Optional: Restart worker on exit
        workers[i].on('exit', function(code, signal) {
            console.log('respawning worker', i);
            spawn(i);
        });
    };

    // Spawn workers.
    for (var i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
        spawn(i);
    }

    // Helper function for getting a worker index based on IP address.
    // This is a hot path so it should be really fast. The way it works
    // is by converting the IP address to a number by removing non numeric
  // characters, then compressing it to the number of slots we have.
    //
    // Compared against "real" hashing (from the sticky-session code) and
    // "real" IP number conversion, this function is on par in terms of
    // worker index distribution only much faster.
    var worker_index = function(ip, len) {
        var s = '';
        for (var i = 0, _len = ip.length; i < _len; i++) {
            if (!isNaN(ip[i])) {
                s += ip[i];
            }
        }

        return Number(s) % len;
    };

    // Create the outside facing server listening on our port.
    var server = net.createServer({ pauseOnConnect: true }, function(connection) {
        // We received a connection and need to pass it to the appropriate
        // worker. Get the worker for this connection's source IP and pass
        // it the connection.
        var worker = workers[worker_index(connection.remoteAddress, num_processes)];
        worker.send('sticky-session:connection', connection);
    }).listen(port);
} else {
    // Note we don't use a port here because the master listens on it for us.
    var server_local = require('./server.js');
    server_local.startServer(0, function(server, io) {


    // Here you might use middleware, attach routes, etc.

    // Don't expose our internal server to the outside.

    // Tell Socket.IO to use the redis adapter. By default, the redis
    // server is assumed to be on localhost:6379. You don't have to
    // specify them explicitly unless you want to change them.
    io.adapter(sio_redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));

    // Here you might use Socket.IO middleware for authorization etc.

    // Listen to messages sent from the master. Ignore everything else.
    process.on('message', function(message, connection) {
        if (message !== 'sticky-session:connection') {
            return;
        }

        // Emulate a connection event on the server by emitting the
        // event with the connection the master sent us.
        server.emit('connection', connection);

        connection.resume();
    });

  });
}
```

server.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var satJS = require('satellite.js');
var express = require('express');
var app = new express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);
var sio = require('socket.io');

...

exports.startServer = function(port, callback) {
  updateSatelliteData(function() {
    server = app.listen(port);
    io = sio(server);
    initalize(io);
    callback(server, io);
    console.log("Server started");
  });
}

function initalize(io) {

  //Web stuff
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
  });

  app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

...

  }
etc.
}
```